# Why don't the Jedi converse with Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, sith

In the movie, Star Wars Episode 1: The Phantom Menace, why don't Qui-Gon or Obi-Wan ever converse with Darth Maul?

It seemed there were opportunities where they could have started a dialogue instead of swinging light sabers furiously.

Why not ask him who he is, what he wanted? Was he a Sith? Did the Jedi assume that Darth Maul only wanted to fight them or was unable to communicate? In all the other episodes, we see plenty of conversation between Jedi and Sith.

Comment: He was visibly evil, they could feel that he was strong in the Force, and they had lightsabers AND kick-ass fight music.  'Talking' was never on the table.

Comment: "He was visibly evil" because he wore black, used a red lightsaber, and his face was black and red? if only morality was always color-coded

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you're talking about the movies, the only time you see communication between Jedi and Sith are when they know each other. Such as Luke and his dear old Dad, or Obi-Wan and Anakin/Vader. While they do talk with Palpitane, that's before they know he's Sith or when they have enough they think they can take him in.

From the start, when they see Darth Maul, he's on the offensive and ready to attack them. Their first encounter is on Tatooine and if Maul were interested in communicating verbally, he could have stopped before coming within dueling range of Qui-Gon.

The Sith are power hungry and it's the nature of the Sith to stop at nothing short than gaining as much power as possible. The Jedi know this; they know what the Sith want, so there's no point in discussing it.

If they did discuss it with Maul, it would be a pattern of appeasement, similar to what happened on Earth before WWII, when Hitler kept demanding more and more until he was finally ready to just start fighting.  Whatever the Sith stated, there would be no reason to believe they would be satisfied with nothing less than control of the galactic government.

You can't negotiate with someone who wants it all, so what's to be gained by talking to them?

-------- Added After Comments -------

Note the situation with Dooku and Kenobi is rather different. First, there's no combat going on, and, second, Kenobi is captured and has one simple goal: to manipulate things to gain his release if possible (and possibly gain information). But Dooku is in control throughout the situation and has no desire to indulge Kenobi.

Comment: Count Dooku, aka Darth Tyranus, had plenty of dialogue with Anakin and Obi-Wan. Is this only because he was Qui-Gon's master, which they know indirectly?

Comment: Oh, yeah -- but that was more along the line of Dooku wanting something from Obi-Wan than Obi-Wan thinking he could get anything from Dooku.  I'll add that when I have time later this morning.

Comment: Apologies for coming in late, but I'm not convinced. The Sith reappear after 1000 years, and the Jedi aren't even **curious**? Of course any replies Maul gave would be untrustworthy, but they might learn something useful anyway. Out-of-universe, it was one of the major problems with Episode I: The antagonist in the climactic duel doesn't have any emotional connection to the other characters, he's just a big scary dude who wants to kill them. The shark in *Jaws* was a better developed character than Darth Maul.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - isn't conversation with the notoriously seductive and manipulative Sith the best way to fall to the Dark Side ?

Answer (score 2):

The Jedi do not converse with Darth Maul, especially in Episode I, because he is too busy attacking them the first time they meet, nearly running down Anakin in the process.

The second time they meet Darth Maul, his intentions are quite clear, though, I agree, they had an opportunity to at least make the attempt at opening a dialogue, but again, weren't really given much opportunity, because as soon as the non-Force users were out of the way, Maul draws his saber-staff, prompting the Jedi to draw their own sabers. Combat immediately follows.

Some are forgetting that even in the final battle, not all the Jedi Masters on the Council agree that it COULD have been a Sith. They don't come to that agreement until after Qui-Gon Gin's death, leading to Obi-Wan Kenobi's promotion to Knight. I will agree however that the editors should not have removed some of Maul's key lines from the film. Gunray asking Maul where he was going only to receive the reply "I have Jedi to exterminate." would have provided a lot more character to his 'strong silent type.'

Answer (score 1):

Darth Maul had a strong hatred for the Jedi and only had thoughts of killing them. He also knew some of their secrets due to Sidious aiding him. It is in the book "Darth Maul, Shadow Hunter." It was beneath Maul's beliefs to even consider communicating with a mere Jedi. Maul only had concerns for training and assassination of his master's enemies.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but doesn't address why the jedi didn't try to start a conversation with Maul. Maul can believe in not talking all he wants, but Qui-Gon still could have asked him who he was or told him to surrender